# Deployment 64-bit windows Delphi Xe7 application over 32-bit Windows XP

Tags: windows, delphi, 32bit-64bit, delphi-xe, firemonkey

I'm trying to deploy and easy application with Delphi Xe7:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Menus,
  FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    MenuItem1: TMenuItem;
    MenuItem2: TMenuItem;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.Windows.fmx MSWINDOWS}
{$R *.Surface.fmx MSWINDOWS}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PopupMenu1.Popup(15,20);
end;

end.
```

Over Windows 7 64 bits is working correctly, but over Windows XP 32 bit, when the button is pressed for showing the popupmen-->appears the error "abstract error"

Any suggestion?

Comment: Since it is not possible to run a 64-bit application on a 32-bit OS, I can only presume that your question is worded poorly.  You probably mean that you are compiling your application for 32 or 64-bit but that you get this error with the 32-bit version when running on 32-bit XP.  Do you get the same error when running the same, 32-bit application on the 64-bit Windows 7 system ?

Comment: AS yoyu says it is impossible to run a 64-bit application on a 32-bit OS. For that reason i compile such application wit Delphi XE7 for 32 bit OS. Everything is ok, but when the popupmenu have to be showed, the application return such error. It is possible i need some library or something but i don't know what can it be.

Comment: And do you get the same error on the 64-bit Windows 7 system that you get when trying to run it on the 32-bit XP ?  If you do then the issue is most likely a bug in the FMX PopupMenu implementation for 32-bit compilation.  I don't have XE7 and cannot reproduce the problem (with 32-bit app on 64-bit Win 7) with XE4, but it's possible that this area of FireMonkey has changed in XE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED.

I have tested with another Windows XP and everything is working correctly. Strange behaviour.

Thanks for all.